Angular Material Datepicker - Localization for Material18+
I use Angular Material 18 and the Datepicker component. I try to use the local variation and try to avoid moment. The reason for this is that moment is deprecated. There I try use the DateFns implementation.
I try to follow the already asked question but I'm not succeeding. At the very moment I have several parts of the app not yet standalone therefor the approach there seems (still) reasonable.
I try to include as mentioned
provider: [
{provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: "de"},
{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: DateFnsAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
{provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_DATE_FNS_FORMATS},
...

This compiles on
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label >Release date</mat-label>
    <input
        formControlName="releaseDate"
        matInput
        [matDatepicker]="picker4release"
    />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker4release"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker4release></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

As soon as I try to open the datepicker I get
core.mjs:7195 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preprocessor')
    at format (format.mjs:371:23)
    at _DateFnsAdapter.format (material-date-fns-adapter.mjs:136:12)
    at get periodButtonDescription (datepicker.mjs:2612:32)
    at MatCalendarHeader_Template (datepicker.mjs:2742:36)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:11791:5)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:13344:7)

Trying as well
registerLocaleData(localeDe);
registerLocaleData(localeEn);

@NgModule({
....
provider: [
        {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: localeDe},


won't help. Any hint how use it properly?

please share a minimal code stackblitz with the issue happening

I was more looking for a working minimal stackblitz example for the DateFns for Material since its mentioned on the Material website. But couldn't find any. Therefore this question.

First make sure you added date-fns to your project.
npm i date-fns

Then add @angular/material-date-fns-adapter using add.
ng add @angular/material-date-fns-adapter

Then you need to add the provider provideDateFnsAdapter as shown in the below comments, it can be added either at the bootstrapApplication level or at the standalone component level.
The core providers you need are.
{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: ja },
{ provide: DateAdapter, useClass: DateFnsAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_DATE_FNS_FORMATS },
provideDateFnsAdapter(),

The component code will look like below. notice that when working with date-fns you need to add the locale using the import import { fr, ja } from 'date-fns/locale';.
import { provideDateFnsAdapter } from '@angular/material-date-fns-adapter';
import { fr, ja } from 'date-fns/locale';

...

...
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-locale-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-locale-example.html',
  styleUrl: 'datepicker-locale-example.css',
  providers: [
    // The locale would typically be provided on the root module of your application. We do it at
    // the component level here, due to limitations of our example generation script.
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: ja },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: DateFnsAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_DATE_FNS_FORMATS },

    // date-fns can be provided globally to your app by adding `provideDateFnsAdapter`
    // to your app config. We provide it at the component level here, due to limitations
    // of our example generation script.
    provideDateFnsAdapter(),
  ],
  ...

Now you can focus on the language switching. Again, we do not provide the locale as a string but as an object whose import is shown above.
Now, we can switch the language by changing the locale object.
import { fr, ja } from 'date-fns/locale';
...

...
french() {
  this._locale.set(fr);
  this._adapter.setLocale(this._locale());
  this.updateCloseButtonLabel('Fermer le calendrier');
}
...

Full Code:
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  OnInit,
  computed,
  inject,
  signal,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  DateFnsAdapter,
  MAT_DATE_FNS_FORMATS,
  provideDateFnsAdapter,
} from '@angular/material-date-fns-adapter';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import {
  DateAdapter,
  MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
  MAT_DATE_LOCALE,
} from '@angular/material/core';
import {
  MatDatepickerIntl,
  MatDatepickerModule,
} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { fr, ja } from 'date-fns/locale';

/** @title Datepicker with different locale */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-locale-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-locale-example.html',
  styleUrl: 'datepicker-locale-example.css',
  providers: [
    // The locale would typically be provided on the root module of your application. We do it at
    // the component level here, due to limitations of our example generation script.

    // Moment can be provided globally to your app by adding `provideDateFnsAdapter`
    // to your app config. We provide it at the component level here, due to limitations
    // of our example generation script.
    provideDateFnsAdapter(),
  ],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DatepickerLocaleExample implements OnInit {
  private readonly _adapter =
    inject<DateAdapter<unknown, unknown>>(DateAdapter);
  private readonly _intl = inject(MatDatepickerIntl);
  private readonly _locale = signal(inject<unknown>(MAT_DATE_LOCALE));
  readonly dateFormatString = computed(() => {
    if (this._locale() === 'ja-JP') {
      return 'YYYY/MM/DD';
    } else if (this._locale() === 'fr') {
      return 'DD/MM/YYYY';
    }
    return '';
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateCloseButtonLabel('カレンダーを閉じる');
  }

  french() {
    this._locale.set(fr);
    this._adapter.setLocale(this._locale());
    this.updateCloseButtonLabel('Fermer le calendrier');
  }

  updateCloseButtonLabel(label: string) {
    this._intl.closeCalendarLabel = label;
    this._intl.changes.next();
  }
}

/**  Copyright 2024 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license */

Stackblitz Demo -> adapter and providers at bootstrapApplication level, hence applies to all datepickers.
Stackblitz Demo -> adapter and providers at component level, hence applies to one datepicker.

Thank you this helps very much. Especially obtaining the part for the locale from the package date-fns/locale is something I've missed. Some q: Why do you use importProvidersFrom(MatNativeDateModule),? If I remove it has no side effects. And why use provideDateFnsAdapter() on the component level? Isn't this provided in the bootstrapping?

AND: Do I need to have registerLocaleData(localeDe) in the app.module? - at least for the Datepicker?

@LeO it works without registerLocaleData(localeDe) so not needed, I think, if any warnings show up, then try it.

@LeO updated my answer, importProvidersFrom(MatNativeDateModule) is not needed my mistake

Sorry, for more questions: If I just paste in the definitions of the {provide...} in the @NgModule it works fine - no need to use provideDateFnsAdapter. Do I miss something? Second: The MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS provided an option to get the timestamp as utc (from e.g. DatePicker). Is this as well possible for the DateFns?

@LeO I would suggest we keep the provideDateFnsAdapter either at the component level or at the bootstrapApplication level, it is essential, since its mentioned in the docs, for the second half, could I get a new question, with more details about this, would like to dig deep and answer it properly
